# What does cd’s `-@` option do?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, cd

So, if I `man cd`, I get the manpage for bash builtins.

If I `cd -?`, I get the following:

```
cd -?
-bash: cd: -?: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
```

I know what the first two options are.  Then I searched for both options.

- For the `-e` option, I found [this answer on the Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65911/an-e-option-to-cd-builtin).
- For the `-@` option, I couldn’t find any explanation.

**My system info:**

- **OS X 10.9** (Mavericks)
- **bash 4.3.18** (installed with the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) package manager for OS X)

However, if I run `which cd`, I get `/usr/bin/cd`.  Homebrew doesn’t touch anything outside of `/usr/local`, so I can only assume this is the system’s `cd`.

**But I can’t find the documentation for that option!**  It’s driving me crazy.

Does anyone know what `-@` does?

Comment: type `help cd` in the terminal and you'll have: `-@  on systems that support it, present a file with extended attributes as a directory containing the file attributes`.

Comment: `which` doesn't know about shell built-in commands like `cd`. `type cd` (or `type -a cd`) gives you better information. Some systems have a `/usr/bin/cd` executable, but it's not useful (except perhaps as a test to see whether you *can* change to a specified directory).

Comment: The `cd` command, including the `-@` option, is documented in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html); type `info bash` and search for `\`cd' `

Comment: `/usr/bin/cd` doesn't even make sense (at least for changing directories), as it would run as a separate process that would not be able to affect the execution environment of its parent. Perhaps `/usr/bin/cd` is something else entirely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a new option (as of bash-4.3). The changelog contains the following description:

> 'cd' has a new `-@' option to browse a file's extended attributes on
>       systems that support O_XATTR.

([changelog](https://openrepos.net/content/nieldk/bash))

Type `help <name>` or `man bash` to get more info on bash commands. (In the bash man page you can search for `cd` by typing `/` followed by a search string and enter. `n` to go to the next hit, shift+`n` to go backwards).

The bash man page contains the following:

> On systems that support it, the -@ option presents the extended 
>   attributes  associated  with  a file  as  a directory.

Comment: but `help cd` works and is faster than searching for the command in `man bash` or `info bash`

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for bash for an explanation.  The relevant portion says:

> If dir begins with a slash (/), then CDPATH is not used.  The  -P  option  causes  cd to use the physical directory structure by resolving symbolic links while traversing  dir  and before processing instances of .. in dir (see also the -P option to the set builtin command); the -L option forces symbolic links to  be followed by resolving the link after processing instances of .. in dir.  If .. appears in dir, it is processed by removing the  immediately previous pathname component from dir, back to a slash or the beginning of dir.  If the  -e  option  is  supplied with  -P,  and  the current working directory cannot be successfully determined after a successful directory  change,  cd  will return  an unsuccessful status.  On systems that support it, the -@ option presents the extended  attributes  associated  with  a file  as  a directory.  An argument of - is converted to $OLDPWD before the directory change is attempted.  If a non-empty directory  name  from  CDPATH is used, or if - is the first argument, and the directory change is successful, the absolute pathname of the  new  working  directory  is written to the standard output.